# Can there be more than one answer for Big O complexity?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, analysis

How would you talk about the following function in terms of Big O Complexity?

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < n && j < 10; j++) {
    //do something in constant time
  }
}
```

In this case I would see worst case is O(n) could I safely ignore the fact it's O(n^2) for values of less than 10 since it's far from the "worst" case.

For a more real world experience. Let's talk about the size complexity of finding if two strings are permutations of each other.  The simple way to do it is to take an a array of integers for all the character values (ascii characters would be 128).

Now if you switch to a vector or hashmap (I would say to just use an array of integers but the example someone used was a hashmap), you get variable size up to 128 characters entered.

We were discussing the size complexity, and I simply said it's O(1) just because in the worst case you'll get 128.  Another person said confidently that it was O(n) up to 128 characters, and becomes a limit of O(1).  We didn't have a definitive answer.

I've never heard using "limits" when dealing with Big O.  So which is correct in this case?  Am I correct in that the correct complexity when judging big O is only to be considered when n is "Big enough"?  Or are there other cases where there can be alternate answers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you calculate big O on a function with a hard limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553958/how-do-you-calculate-big-o-on-a-function-with-a-hard-limit)

Comment: IMHO the inner loop is just O(1). Then again, the same would also be true for a loop like `for (int i = 0; i < (n < 1000 ? pow(10, n) : 10); i++)`, which never does more than 10^1000 iterations...

Answer (score 3):

> Can there be more than one answer?

Yes, the big O notation expresses something like "smaller or equal" so if your effort is in O(n) it is also in O(n log n) or in O(n^2). However, one is usually interested in a tight bound.

> Let's talk about the size complexity of finding if two strings are permutations of each other

The set of possible characters in the strings is finite so the size complexity is in O(1). In the light of what I said before, it is also in O(n); but the tighter bound is O(1).

Comment: To complement the answer, sometimes the description of the encoding size varies. The runtime complexity for algorithms for matrix multiplication is usually stated in `n` while the input is of size `n*n`, which can be confusing. More specifically, a naive matrix multiplication using the definition would yield a running time of `O(n^3)`, but this means that the running time is cubic in `n`, not in the size of the input, which is `n*n`. Consequently, the running time would be `O(n^1.5)` in the input size.

Answer (score 0):

There are several questions in your post. Also, they are not really programming questions. I will try a helpful answer:

The loop is both in `O(n)` and `O(n^2)` (please read about the definition of Big-Oh, Wikipedia e.g.). The loop would also be `O(n^3)` or `O(n^4)` if you want. But the idea is to find the "lowest" `O(f(n))` possible, which in your case would be `O(n)`, to be more precise `O(10*n)`, which is the same **set** as `O(n)` really.

The order of growth (or complexity if you want) of an algorithm is a function of the size of its input. So in your case, *are two strings permutations of each other?*, it depends on the size of the strings. Assuming that the size of the smallest string is `n`, and that you have to read the entire input for the decision problem, you have at least `n` steps (which makes it clear it cannot be `O(1)`).

The limited size of the array of hash map is the order of growth of the algorithm's memory (space complexity), and if you use only the ASCII set then I can see that it is `O(1)` too.

Comment: OP is asking about the space complexity for detecting permutations, not time complexity.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the comment, I am rather confused. Is the last sentence not about space complexity ?

Comment: Is the third paragraph not about time complexity?

Comment: I see now what you mean. I used *algorithm's memory* instead of *space complexity*. My wording is maybe unfortunate. I hope with this comment that it is clearer now.